# ASP.NET Business Logic Layer

Tags: asp.net, business-logic-layer

I have a business logic layer object for my customers. It has a lot of different fields, around 100: Id, Name, and other fields.

I'm retrieving the customers un a data grid (RadGrid). Obviously in the grid I'm just retrieving a few fields.

The question is: if the business logic layer object has too many fields, even if I don't show all of them in the data grid, is it going to slow down the page? do you think it'd be a good idea to create another object for my customers for the lists?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It wil take extra time to populate the server side list, but the key consideration is teh amount of data passed to the clinet, especially as a copy of the data will probably go into viewstate as well and when submitting the form this data will come back (through viewstate)

Rather than create a new object you could just use LINQ on you business objects to reduce the amount of data to pass forwards.